# Pytest fixture finalizer TypeError 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: typeerror, pytest, finalizer, fixture

I have a simple pytest fixture to ensure that the test data file is present (and deleted at the end of the test), but if gives me the error described in the title.

```
@pytest.fixture
def ensure_test_data_file(request):
    data_file = server.DATA_FILE_NAME
    with open(data_file, 'w') as text_file:
        text_file.write(json.dumps(TEST_DATA))
        text_file.close()

    print(os.path.abspath(data_file))

    request.addfinalizer(os.remove(data_file))
```

If I remove the finalizer, it works (except that the file is not deleted). Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a function object to `request.addfinalizer` - what you're doing is actually *calling* `os.remove(data_file)`, which returns `None`, and thus you're doing `request.addfinalizer(None)`.

Here you'd use `request.addfinalizer(lambda: os.remove(data_file))` or `request.addfinalizer(functools.partial(os.remove, data_file))` to get a callable with the argument already "applied", but which isn't actually called.

However, I'd recommend using `yield` in the fixture instead ([docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#fixture-finalization-executing-teardown-code)), which makes this much cleaner by letting you "pause" your fixture and run the test in between:

```
@pytest.fixture
def ensure_test_data_file(request):
    data_file = server.DATA_FILE_NAME
    with open(data_file, 'w') as text_file:
        text_file.write(json.dumps(TEST_DATA))
        text_file.close()

    print(os.path.abspath(data_file))

    yield

    os.remove(data_file)
```

Comment: I modified the function a little yesterday before implementing your solution, but it does not like me having a return in the fixture before the yield statement, so I went with the lambda one.

Comment: What do you need a `return` in the fixture for?

Comment: @TheCompiler, you can pass a value from the fixture to the test function using `yield` or `return`. Take a look e.g. at the built-in `tmpdir` fixture – that one passes a path to the created temporary directory.

Comment: @TheCompiler, note that `@pytest.yield_fixture` is [deprecated](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/yieldfixture.html). Just use `@pytest.fixture` instead.

Comment: @akaihola I was asking @Amaranth why they need a `return` before the `yield` (which makes no sense), see their comment above. And I'm aware about `yield_fixture`, I was [involved](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/1461) in that change myself - but that happened after this answer was written ;-) I'll edit it.

Comment: @TheCompiler I must have been tired 1.5 yrs ago – now the discussion above makes perfect sense to me up until my comment... Thanks for the link to the pytest issue, it's always interesting to peek behind the scenes for one of those workhorse packages everyone uses and relies on!